# Adding text to links when not on the homepage

Tags: jquery

I'm using fullpage.js in a Wordpress theme and on the homepage the main menu links to different sections on the homepage via "#section-1, #section-2" and so forth. Then on other pages the main menu obviously doesn't link back to the different sections homepage because its just "#section-1" in the menu link. With out making another menu for other pages is there a way (maybe using jQuery) to add the base url to the main menu links so when its no on the homepage they would be "homepage/#section-1" ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

sThis doesn't need jquery, just add a custom header for your pages and change the menu links in this header accordingly:

Copy the same **header.php** file and rename it to **header-pages.php** and edit its menu links to the following:

```
<ul>
     <li data-menuanchor="home">
         <a href="/">home</a>
     </li>
     <li data-menuanchor="about">
         <a href="/#about">about us</a>
     </li>
     ...
</ul>
```

In your pages use the following to import your customized header: (make sure it's on the first line of course)

```
<?php get_header('pages'); ?>
```

PS: the scrolling process after link redirection will also be animated :)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks that is one way of doing it but I don't think I can use it as I have no idea how many sections or pages are going to be added as the site is not going to be used by me. Hence looking into a link add on if not the homepage.

Comment: Regardless how many sections/pages are going to be created, you can add your get_header('pages') in the default pages which will be used when creating news posts/pages, ones like: single.php (defaults single pages for posts), page.php (defaults pages template), archive.php (default archive pages template) ... However anything can be done with jquery but it's not the right way to do it.

Comment: The sections on the homepage are different to the pages on the site, (the pages are not on the homepage) the user could add 10 or 20 sections on the homepage and have any number of pages not on the homepage. I want the ability to go back to any of the sections from any page using the main menu, so I don't see how your way can dynamically account for sections unknown.